# WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['Variable:0'] when minimizing the loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['Variable:0'] when minimizing the loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss` argument?

I have no clue why it keeps repeating the error message above. The code I have is as follows:

```
class GARCH_NN():
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, q, p):
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.q = q
        self.p = p
        self.weights = {
            'input_to_hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim])),
            'hidden_to_hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.hidden_dim, self.hidden_dim])),
            'hidden_to_output': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim])),
            'output_to_var': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.output_dim, self.q])),
            'var_to_var': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.q, self.q])),
            'var_to_ar': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.q, self.p])),
            'ar_to_ar': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.p, self.p])),
        }
        self.biases = {
            'input_to_hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.hidden_dim])),
            'hidden_to_output': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.output_dim])),
            'output_to_var': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.q])),
            'var_to_ar': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.p])),
            'ar_to_ar': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([self.p])),
        }

    def garch_forward(self, inputs):
        
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs.astype('float32'), self.weights['input_to_hidden']) + self.biases['input_to_hidden'])
        for i in range(inputs.shape[0]):
            hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(inputs[i,:].astype('float32'), axis=0), self.weights['input_to_hidden']) + 
                                tf.matmul(hidden, self.weights['hidden_to_hidden']) + self.biases['input_to_hidden'])
        
        output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden, self.weights['hidden_to_output']) + self.biases['hidden_to_output'])
        var = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(output, self.weights['output_to_var']) + self.biases['output_to_var'])
        var = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(var, self.weights['var_to_var']) + self.biases['output_to_var'])
        ar = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(var, self.weights['var_to_ar']) + self.biases['var_to_ar'])
        ar = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(ar, self.weights['ar_to_ar']) + self.biases['var_to_ar'])
        return var, ar

    def loss_fn(self, inputs):
        var, ar = self.garch_forward(inputs)
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(var - inputs[:,self.output_dim:])) + tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(ar - inputs[:,:self.output_dim]))

    def train_step(self, inputs, optimizer):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = self.loss_fn(inputs)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, list(self.weights.values()) + list(self.biases.values()))
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, list(self.weights.values()) + list(self.biases.values())))

    def train(self, inputs, epochs, optimizer):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            self.train_step(inputs, optimizer)
            if epoch % 100 == 0:
                loss = self.loss_fn(inputs)
                print('Epoch:', epoch, 'Loss:', loss.numpy())
```

```
input_dim = 5
hidden_dim = 10
output_dim = 3
q = 2
p = 1
num_epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01

WTI_ANN_GARCH = GARCH_NN(input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, q, p)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)
WTI_ANN_GARCH.train(WTI_change_data_before_2018.dropna().head(5).T.values, num_epochs, optimizer)
```

I tried locating the source of the error using print() statments but had no luck. I commented out the last two lines of the train_step function which got rid of the warning, but of course made the code not do any gradient decent what-so-ever. Maybe it is something wrong with those last two lines but also I do not think so. Not sure and I feel stumped.